# Instant notification on Android app based on Web Data changes

Tags: php, android, https

I am currently building an Android app for my website and I want to implement a certain feature for my app. Here is a brief description:

Currently my website has so-called "Announcements" (These are simple messages that can be sent via admin panel by one of the administrators). A user, who is logging in through the website is able to view these announcements and therefore read the contents of those.

Inside my app, I am able to view those announcements and read content as well, but I would also love to notify my user of any new notification as soon as one appears. However, here is where I face a problem.

Due to the fact, that the website does not have any API for applications, my app basically gets the XML data of Announcement and then parses it to the data inside the app and then I am able to show the data to user inside an app, same can be achieved for notifications. Using Work Manager, I am able to schedule periodic work with 15min (minimum) delay and then show whenever any new announcement has been posted by comparing ID's of announcements inside my app.

As you can see, it is very troublesome and not very convenient way of handling this, moreover, 15 minutes is a very long delay in my case, and I need user to receive that notification in the app as soon as administrator posts one on the website.

What I think would be a good implementation in this case:

- Instead of sending HTTP request every 15 minutes to the server, android app would need to have a listener, that is observing the contents of "Announcements" of my website
- With that in mind, Website would need to have some kinds of Listenable container that stores those Announcements
- As soon as contents of "Announcements" changes, my app fetches said "Announcements" and after some extra actions, it displays them as notifications

And this is where I face the problem, since I am not sure how exactly, and what exactly I should be using for both website and android app to achieve this kind of behavior. Please, point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Use some third-party service like [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or implement a custom client/server logic with a near real-time messaging protocol such as [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). Latter is obviously going to be super complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve, can be done using [**webSockets**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). The purpose of webSocket is exactly to avoid making tons of requests just to look for updates, instead it creates something like an "infinite connection" that updates your frontend whenever some event are dispatched from your webServer. You can read a good article [here](https://medium.com/@mena.meseha/complete-guide-to-achieve-websocket-real-time-communication-with-laravel-broadcast-c6211fa589e5).

This describes the use with Laravel and a popular service for managing websockets without too many headaches, [**Pusher**](https://pusher.com/).

I hope this helps on pointing you in the right direction!